# Uncaught exception 'PDOException'

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Currently I'm trying to run this as an update, I'm getting the **error message:**

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]:
>   Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound'

Not really sure where I'm going wrong with this one.

HTML:

```
<input  type="text" name="sortId" value="<?php echo $name['sort_id']; ?>" >
<input  type="input" name="sortName" value="<?php echo $name['sort']; ?>" >
```

PHP:

```
$sortId = $_POST['sortId'];
$sortName = $_POST['sortName'];

$sql = "UPDATE `sorts` SET `sort` = :sortName WHERE `sort_id` = :sortId ";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);     
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't binding your tokens with values, it should look like this:

```
$sortId = $_POST['sortId']; 
$sortName = $_POST['sortName'];
```

( be aware that you should always filter/sanitize your POSTs)

```
$sql = "UPDATE `sorts` SET `sort` = :sortName WHERE `sort_id` = :sortId";    
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bindParam(':sortName', $sortName);
$stmt->bindParam(':sortId', $sortId);
$stmt->execute();
```

For more about bindParam and bindValue, rerfer to:

[bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

[bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I'll accept as answer shortly.  The links are great I've bookmarked them should I need later again.

Comment: cool mate, just ask if you need any clarification

Comment: Will do thanks again.